# Azure function app powershell triggers twice/thrice

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I got an Azure Alert with an action group that includes my Azure Function App. 
The function app is on a consumption plan 
However when 1 alert is fired I get two and sometimes three function app replies. Currently testing with email, but can be Teams/Slack/Twilio or something else

I've looked over my code several times but cannot find why it's running several times.
Could this be a cold start issue?
I shouldn't hit the timeout since it finishes in a few seconds
Do I need the following code block?

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
})
```

For example the alert triggered 11/14/2019, 4:59:02 AM
The function app produced three replies:

- 05:00
- 05:00
- 05:01

```
using namespace System.Net
using namespace System.Web

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request) 
# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
$alert = $Request.RawBody | convertfrom-json

function New-TypeTable([object[]]$columns)
{
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($c in $columns)
    {
        switch ($c.type)
        {
            "datetime" { $type = [datetime] }
            "real" { $type = [decimal] }
            default { $type = [string] }
        }
        $hash.Add($c.name, $type)
    }
    $hash
}

function Set-Culture([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture)
{
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
}

#Set locale to swedish for datetime
Set-Culture sv-SE
#Set variables for later use
$alertRule = $alert.data.essentials.alertRule
$alertDescription = $alert.data.essentials.description
$tables = $alert.data.alertContext.SearchResults.tables

foreach ($table in $tables)
{
    $cHash = New-TypeTable -columns $table.columns
    [string[]]$keys = $cHash.Keys
    $tableInfo = foreach ($row in $table.rows)
    {
        $psObj = New-Object PSObject
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $row.Count; $i++)
        {
            $value = $row[$i]
            $type = $cHash[$i]
            #Round the value of AggregatedValue and CounterValue
            if ($keys[$i] -eq "AggregatedValue" -Or $keys[$i] -eq "CounterValue") {
                $value = [math]::Round($value,1)
            }
            #Set the value of TimeGenerated to a specific format
            if ($keys[$i] -eq "TimeGenerated") {
                $value = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}" -f $value
            }
            #Don't add Null values
            if($value) {
                $psObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $keys[$i] -Value ($value -as $type)
            }
        }
        $psObj
    }
}
#Write-Information $tableInfo -verbose
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {width: 750px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
"@
#Create HTML-table from the object
$Body = $tableInfo | ConvertTo-Html -head $Header
```

I've added RunOnStartup = false to the function and no difference. Seems like it gets triggered three times by the alert. But the alert only fires once.

```
DATE (UTC) SUCCESS RESULT CODE DURATION (MS) 
2019-11-18 20:31:16.092 204 799.4648 
2019-11-18 20:29:32.032 204 23197.282 
2019-11-18 20:29:17.956 204 41919.4075
```

Comment: So you mean you get three emails from the alert ? And may I know if you create application insight when you create the function app ? If yes, you can see some more information about the running of the function in application insight.

Comment: Yes I get three emails and sometimes two from the alert. I did not create app insights but I could spin it up for troubleshooting purposes

Comment: May I know which signal you choose in the "condition" of your alert ?

Comment: Resource: log analytics workspace

Condition: Signal Type: Log search Signal Name: Custom Log search

Actions: Action group with Azure Function

Comment: We have a function app which sends alerts to Teams when an app insights web test fails. Ever since they upgraded the alerts, we've been getting 2-3 alerts on ours as well. And yes, we upgraded the function app to deal with their new payload format. Not sure why we get multiple alerts, haven't looked too closely, but it may not be an issue with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay here's an update after a long case with Azure Support. If anyone that ends up here.

Azure Alert action group using an Azure App Function is at its core an webhook call. This means that it's has the same restrictions/constrains as a regular webhook.
See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups#webhook)

After 10 seconds it retries and after another 100 seconds it retries again. If you use an Azure app function on consumption it might take longer for the app function to cold start. This means it can be called up to three times because the app function will run each time it's called even if it takes time to cold start the function (sometimes it starts quicker and you only get two runs and if it's already running you get one run).

Depending on what you're doing this might be a problem. Suggestion by Azure Support in **bold** and the other are my possible solutions (do note that my suggestions will incur **costs**)

- **Make the function idempotent**
- **Make the function stateful**
- Use an app service plan with always on
- Use an Logic App
- If Powershell use an Automation Account runbook